# HtmlHelper para un input tipo FILE

Tags: html, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-5, razor

Tengo una pequeña duda, necesito generar un input de tipo File para guardar imágenes en mi BD, estoy usando vistas con razor en asp.net mvc 5, pero no logro encontrar como hacerlo mediante el `HtmlHelper`, pero veo que no te proporciona ninguno para este tipo de input, ¿alguna idea de como lograrlo?

No anexo código ya que solo me interesa por el momento tenerlo en mi vista usando un HtmlHelper pero sin funcionalidad.

Comment: exactamente eso, muchas gracias :)

Comment: Supongo que queres hacerlo asi para que el binding te enlace automaticamente el valor de ese input a la propiedad correspondiente de tu modelo.. si es asi, igual podes hacerlo con HTML puro, y en el action de tu controller pones que reciba como parametro FormCollection.. dentro de ese array de valores vas a tener el valor que se cargo en el input.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Si tienes el atributo en tu modelo podrías hacerlo de este modo

```
@Html.EditorFor(m=>m.Archivo, new { htmlAttributes = new { @type="file" } })
```

y si no lo tienes del siguiente

```
@Html.Editor("Archivo", new { htmlAttributes = new { @type="file" } })
```

solo tienes que agregar el tipo archivo en los atributos del helper